# Image not being displayed using Media Query

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am using bootstrap for my images. It displays the smaller image in the browser as I am using `visible-xs` with `img-responsive`.

However when I am trying to load the bigger image using `media query`, the screen is just blank.

I have checked the location of the image and it is there.

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to why bigger image is not being displayed with `media query`?

```
<div class="container">
<div id="my_img"><img id="pic" src="images/flower.jpg" class="img-responsive visible-xs"></div>
</div>
```

and in the CSS file

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #pic{
    background:url('images/flower-1200.jpg') no-repeat;
  }    
}
```

Comment: Should you not rather set the background image of `#my_img` as the `#pic` tag will not be visible at that resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your `.css` files are most likely in a `css` folder.

If that is the case, you need to use the relative location of the image based off the location of your `.css` file. most likely this:

`background:url('../images/flower-1200.jpg') no-repeat;`

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out here, I wasn't accessing the path correctly. It worked like this for me background:url(../images/flower-1200.jpg) no-repeat;

Answer (score 4):

if you are using the `visible-xs` class then  according to [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities), it only going to appear in extra-small screens, hiding in the rest of the screens.

[image: SS]

If you are trying to load a new image (using the `background`) then you have to apply to the parent `#my_img` since it doesn't have the  `visible-xs` class.

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #my_img {
    background: url('//lorempixel.com/1600/900') no-repeat;
    height:900px;
    max-width:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
      <div id="my_img">
        <img id="pic" src="//dummyimage.com/100x100" class="img-responsive visible-xs">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As [dippas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3448527/dippas) mentioned, your `#pic` image will not be visible at 1200px because of the `visible-xs` class so you would need to set the background image of your `#my_img` instead. Be sure to provide the appropriate dimensions in your CSS of the image in question.

Comment: @media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #my-img{
  background:url('images/flower-1200.jpg') no-repeat;
  }     //still it doesn't shows the image

}

Comment: @artist take a look at my snippet it might help you out